# I want to combine 2 array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

This is HTML of two array. I need to click ul.left and ul.right. (example- 1&a, 1&c, 2&b ...) When I click the left array and the right array, I need to get the left/right combination in the div.input.

```
<ul class="left">
  <li><button>1</button></li>
  <li><button>2</button></li>
  <li><button>3</button></li>
</ul>

<ul class="right">
  <li><button>a</button></li>
  <li><button>b</button></li>
  <li><button>c</button></li>
</ul>

<div class="input"> </div>
```

Javascript:

```
const arrayRight = document.querySelectorAll('.right li');
const arrayLeft = document.querySelectorAll('.left li');
const input = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
Array.from(arrayRight).addEventListener('click', el => {
  Array.from(arrayLeft).addEventListener('click', ele => {
    input.appendChild(span);
    span.textContent = '${ele.innerText} / ${el.innerText}';
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add your code. So we can help you

Comment: You will need to show your Javascript code as well.

Comment: @Link const arrayRight = document.querySelectorAll(.right li); 
const arrayLeft = document.querySelectorAll(.left li);
const input = document.getElementsByClassName(‘input’);

Array.from(arrayRight).addEventListener(‘click’, el => {
  Array.from(arrayLeft).addEventListener(‘click’, ele => {
       const span= document.createElement(span);  input.appendChild(span);
       span.textContent = ‘${ele.innerText} / ${el.innerText}’;
       ...
});
});

Comment: Please add these kind of details to the Question itself in the future as anyone who is looking to help will require these details to understand the problem. I have resolved it, please check my answer.

Comment: @Link I’ll try. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it. document.querySelectorAll returns a node list, if you want to add event listeners, you need to loop through that nodelist using forEach or a similar loop (for...of, classic for etc.)

```js
const arrayRight = document.querySelectorAll('.right li');
const arrayLeft = document.querySelectorAll('.left li');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

arrayLeft.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input.innerHTML = `<span>${element.textContent} / ${arrayRight[index].textContent}</span>`;
  });
});

arrayRight.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input.innerHTML = `<span>${arrayLeft[index].textContent} / ${element.textContent}  </span>`;
  });
});
```

```html
      <ul class="left">
        <li><button>1</button></li>
        <li><button>2</button></li>
        <li><button>3</button></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="right">
        <li><button>a</button></li>
        <li><button>b</button></li>
        <li><button>c</button></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="input"></div>
```

Comment: Also, never add an event listener inside another event listener, because, if you do that, your inner event listener will only work once you click on the outer event listener's element. So, unless you want that behavior you should make sure to not nest event listeners.